# How to connect ICommand and VisualStateManager together

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, visualstatemanager, icommand

How can I let my controls on the window know that their states should be changed. I have to use ICommand and since controls can have different states (Enable/Disable , Checked/Unchecked ...) have to handle them with VisualStateManager.

This could be a possible scenario:
When Record button is clicked(Checked) the other controls in the window should be uncheckable and once the recording is finished they should be checkable and many other scenarios.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the help of interaction and interactivity. See if it helps.

Add below references in your XAML

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

You can bind your `ICommand` and provide a `VisualState` name that will be applied when `Button` is clicked

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourICommand}" /> 
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="YourVisualStateName" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

If you don't have Blend 4, you can install the [Blend 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10801) to get the current behavior assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Nitesh for your response. Will give it a try and will update you.